# Be notified on new comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications

Hi, is there a way to be notfied about new comments in subscribed threads, like with the actual notification system that works for answers?

Answer (score 2):

When you mark a question as a favourite (by clicking the star below the votes-buttons) you will see new answers *and comments* when you click on the envelope and go to the [favorites] tab. The automatic notification (highlighting the envelope) is [a bit buggy though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63847/favourites-changed-notification-doesnt-work-properly), so you may have to manually select "today" or "this week" to really see all that happened.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t. You could, of course, try to post this as a feature-request and see if it resonates with the developers.

Comment: How can you actually get know if someone posted a comment on one of your answers?

Comment: @maroxe The little envelope beside your display name on the top bar will turn yellow, notifying you of new comments. They are displayed under the "Responses" section there. Of course this is only true for your answers and questions, or if some one explicitly replies to you, like what I'm doing here using "@username"

Comment: @Yi Jiang - It's only true if you reply with @username and the username has commented on the post, posted it, or edited it. Otherwise it won't work.