# Is it possible to be notified about new answers to and comments on bookmarked questions?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, notifications, bookmarks

I get notified by **email** about new answers to and comments on questions posted by me, as well as about comments on my answers.

> Is it possible for me to be notified by **email** about new answers to and comments on questions bookmarked by me? Could that be made an option for me?

I am aware of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63965/321268) (of 2010):

> When you mark a question as a favourite (by clicking the star below the votes-buttons) you will see new answers and comments when you click on the envelope and go to the [favorites] tab. The automatic notification (highlighting the envelope) is a bit buggy though, so you may have to manually select "today" or "this week" to really see all that happened.

However, now, when I click on the envelope, I don't even see a [favorites] tab, nor do I see selections "today" or "this week".

**Edit:** I appreciate the answer by user1271772 and a (now deleted) comment by another user informing me about the rather new Follow feature, which is certainly helpful. However, I'd prefer to get such notifications by email, just as I do concerning new answers to and comments on questions posted by me, as well as comments on my answers. I very rarely remember about, or use, the SE Inbox button.

Comment: Unread inbox notifications do end-up in your e-mail, if you've set that preference in your userprofile.

Comment: @rene : Thank you very much for this comment. In my user profile, under Edit Email Settings, I have the Inbox line set to 3 hrs. So, is this it? I mean, will this let me see the notifications about the Follow'ed posts in my email?

Comment: I expect that to work, yes. If that doesn't work I would call it a bug or I missed an Meta post that explains why those follow notifications are excluded from the email roll-up.

Comment: @rene : Yes, this does seem to be working. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "Follow" button below each post. It's different from bookmarking, and it will allow you to get notifications in the top-right corner of your page when you're logged in, when people write comments on the post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I have upvoted it). The Follow feature is certainly helpful. However, I'd prefer to get such notifications by email, just as I do concerning new answers to and comments on questions posted by me, as well as comments on my answers. I have almost never used the SE Inbox button.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Activity on followed posts will create an item to your stackexchange inbox and you can enable email notifications for unread items in your inbox.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : Thank you very much for this comment. In my user profile, under Edit Email Settings, I have the Inbox line set to 3 hrs. So, is this it? I mean, will this let me see the notifications about the Follow'ed posts in my email?

Comment: yes, you will get emails about posts you follow, juts with a 3 hour delay.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : Yes, this does seem to be working. Thank you very much again!